# Error install rdiscount in windows 7

Tags: windows, rdiscount

I am trying to install rdiscount gem but encountered the following error.

How can I install rdiscount in windows 7?

```
C:\>gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb checking for random()... no checking for srandom()... no checking for rand()... yes checking for srand()... yes checking size of unsigned long... 4 checking size of unsigned int... 4 creating Makefile


                 from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../i
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:40,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:223,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from rdiscount.c:3: c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:229:23 c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:238:23 c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:238:23 c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windef.h:241:24 rdiscount.c: In function 'rb_rdiscount_to_html': rdiscount.c:19:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_rdiscount__get_f rdiscount.c:19:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code rdiscount.c:32:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code rdiscount.c: In function 'rb_rdiscount_toc_content': rdiscount.c:68:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code make: *** [rdiscount.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7.1/ext/gem_

C:\>
```

Answer (score 1):

I still cant get it work so have to use the old version.

```
gem install rdiscount -v=1.6.8 --platform=ruby
```

EDIT ON 2013 March 15th

The old gem give me other error.

I change to used

```
gem install RedCloth -v=4.2.9 –platform=ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Ruby and/or RDiscount.

The latest RDiscount (2.0.7.3) should work on Ruby 1.9.3 or later.